# How enable "show this folder how address book" fo contact folder outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have add-in outlook.I create contact folder and add some contactitems.
How I can programmatically make this folder as show address book?

Answer (score 0):

Set the MAPIFolder.ShowAsOutlookAB property to true.